# Animating both position and rotation in CAAnimationGroup makes position not updated in the end

Tags: ios, rotation, position, caanimation

I was trying to animate both `position` and `rotation` property of a `UIView` using an explicit animation and the result is that the `rotation` was successfully updated but the `position` of the view did **not** update although I updated both the layer's `position` and `rotation` property to its final value right after I add the animation to the view's layer(I guess it is so called *explicit-override-implicit* animation technique?).

Here is my code:

```
CABasicAnimation *move = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
move.fromValue = @(self.square.center.y);
move.toValue = @(300);

CABasicAnimation *rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotate.fromValue = @(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0));
rotate.toValue = @(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45));

CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
group.duration = 1.0;
group.animations = @[move, rotate];

self.square.center = CGPointMake(self.square.center.x, 300);
self.square.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4);
[self.square.layer addAnimation:group forKey:nil];
```

If I implement the position or rotation animation separately, the code performs well and I got the expected results. But when it combines into the `CAAnimationGroup`, the position just won't update to the final value in the end.
Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this: of course with your values:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
   self.square.center = CGPointMake(10, 10);
   self.square.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90);
 }completion:nil];
```